# Python Class - Can't find out how to use method return value within another method

Tags: python, class, python-class

So this is the class i'm testing:

```python
class Test:

    def find_string(self, string):
        self.string = string
        return string.find(string)

    def add_string(self, string):
        found = self.find_string('bar')

        if found == -1:
            string = string + ' bar'
            
        return string
```

Here is my setup:

```python
test_string = 'foo'

Test1 = Test()
new_string = Test1.add_string(string)
```

Results

```
Expected result: foo bar
Result: foo
```

If I replace the method call in add_string with the direct function find() it works fine. Please help me.

Comment: maybe you should use `print()` to see what you get in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and  it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: `string.find(string)` is always going to return `0`. I'm not sure what you expect that expression to do, but it is not doing it.

Comment: your `string.find(string)` does `"bar".find("bar")` so it gives `0`  - You should debug your code to see what it readly do. And when you run directly `find()` then probably you do `"foo".find("bar")` and this gives `-1` . In both functions you use variable `string` which can mislead.

Comment: maybe you should use `self.string = string` in `add_string()` (instead of `find_string()`) and later in `find_string()` use `self.string.find(string)` instead of `string.find(string)` - and then you will have `"foo"` in `self.string` and `"bar"` in `string` so finally `self.string.find(string)` will mean `"foo".find("bar")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me all problem is that variables have similar names and this can be misleading.

Your `string.find(string)` means `"bar".find("bar")` but you expect `"foo".find("bar")`

You would have to use `self.string = string` in `add_string()` (instead of `find_string()`) and later in `find_string()` use `self.string.find(string)` instead of `string.find(string)` - and then you will have `"foo"` in `self.string` and `"bar"` in `string` so finally `self.string.find(string)` will mean `"foo".find("bar")`

```
class Test:

    def find_string(self, string):
        return self.string.find(string)

    def add_string(self, string):
        self.string = string

        found = self.find_string('bar')

        if found == -1:
            string = string + ' bar'
            
        return string

# --- main ---

test_string = 'foo'

test = Test()   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables 
new_string = test.add_string(test_string)

print(new_string)
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)